Can the air have to travel slower than the aeroplane for the plane to experience a forward force?

The speeds are relative to the ground.
Firstly, I don't understand how the speed of the air adds onto the horizontal speed of the plane. Since, the air moves slower than the plane in the horizontal I would expect the plane to slow down. It's like someone pulling you back right?
Secondly, for sake of argument let's say the air exerts a force towards north west causing the plane to move in the same direction. My teacher told me that eventually, the speed of the air gets added onto the plane's. Could someone please explain how that's the case? Or why not.

Does a canoe on a river move relative to the ground? (Now the canoe does not have to be moving relative to the river to stay afloat, but the plane has to move relative to the surrounding air to get lift and stay up.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When an aircraft is cruising with constant horizontal velocity, the force due the aircraft engines is balanced by the drag due to air resistance. The air resistance is a function of the velocity of the air relative to the velocity of the aircraft (in fact it is proportional to the relative velocity squared). If the aircraft was originally in still air and then encounters a following wind the velocity of the aircraft relative to the air drops and the air resistance drops. The forces are now not balanced and the aircraft accelerates until its velocity relative to the air is back to where it was before, but its ground speed will have increased to the aircraft's original velocity plus the wind velocity. The aircraft accelerates because the force supplied by its propulsion system exceeds the drag force when there is a following wind until equilibrium is re-established.
The reverse is also true. In an extreme example, if a small aircraft (or model aircraft) encounters a head wind equal to its normal flying velocity in still air, its ground speed will drop to zero, but it will still be flying because the air speed over its wings is maintained. The aircraft would effectively be hovering in one spot!
